# Can I restrict Endpoints with dry-yasg with this type of view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I have the following in my views.py

I've been reading the documentation and trying to work out is there a way to exclude certain endpoints for this view.

```
from EoX.models import Vendor
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from .serializers import VendorSerializer
from url_filter.integrations.drf import DjangoFilterBackend
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class VendorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
    queryset = Vendor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VendorSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['name',]
```

I can exclude the view all together with

`schema=None`

I tried decorating it with

```
@method_decorator(name='list', decorator=swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_description="description from swagger_auto_schema via method_decorator"
))
```

and that changes the description of the 'get' endpoint.

but trying

```
@method_decorator(name='list', decorator=swagger_auto_schema(methods=['get'],
    operation_description="description from swagger_auto_schema via method_decorator"
))
```

throws an error

`AssertionError:`method`or`methods`can only be specified on @action or @api_view views`

Is this a bug? or just not a supported feature, and is there a way to accomplish what I am trying?

Many thanks.

Comment: So why not define the `list` method and decorate it directly?